# Can I remove the Recent Photos without disabling the People Widget?

Tags: gmail, widgets

Google has added a box displaying recently received photos in Gmail to their People Widget, which can present a huge privacy concern when checking your email in a public place:

[image: Recent Photos]

I know that I remove this by [disabling the entire People Widget](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/LMZIwDXFTo4) using:

> Settings > General > People Widget > Hide the people widget

The rest of the widget is helpful, though. How can I keep it while removing just the recent photos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the Recent Photos box with a single custom CSS rule.

First, install [Stylish for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe), then navigate to Gmail.

Locate your Stylish options and select *"Write new style... for mail.google.com"*

Add the following to your new Style:

```
div.am0{display:none;}
```

For example, using Firefox, your style should look like the following:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("mail.google.com") {
  div.am0{display:none;}
}
```

Now the Recent Photos section of the People Widget will not be displayed* while you are using that browser (and as long as Stylish and the style are enabled.)

---

<sup>* I believe that the Recent Photos section is the only `div.am0`, and will always be hidden by this style, but if anyone notices otherwise, please let me know.</sup>